# WordPress 5.8 Beta 3 Widget Block: widget_id is undefined when a widget is placed

Tags: widgets

I am not sure whether this is already under discussion.
While playing with the new Widget block of 5.8 Beta 3, I got the following notice:

```
Undefined index: widget_id
```

I am only trying to create an element inside the widget() method:

```
<?php
public function widget( $args, $instance ) { ?>
   <div id="element-<?= $args['widget_id'] ?>">...</div>
<?php }
```

However, when I switch to the classic Widget page more, the error goes away and a proper widget_id is returned.

```
<?php
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
   if( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) { $args['widget_id'] = $this->id; } ?>
   <div id="element-<?= $args['widget_id'] ?>">...</div>
<?php }
```

The undefined notice does go away with the above modification, but `$this->id` is always `-1`. In general, an element with ID like `element--1`, is fine, but the problem starts when multiple instances of the same widget are placed and JavaScript is unable to locate the right element. The ID of each instance becomes the same.

How to grab the ID of the current widget while on a Block based widget page?

Comment: Is this your actual code? You don't appear to be actually outputting the ID, you just have text that looks like PHP inside the HTML. You need to properly echo it: `id="element-<?php echo $args['widget_id']; ?>"`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `php` tags. Corrected them now. But `$args['widget_id']` is always undefined. The tags were missing in this post only.

Comment: I haven't played with the 5.8 beta myself, but if this is adding widgets to the block editor then it seems likely, and probably intentional, that an ID isn't generated for the widget before that's happened, and the widget may be rendered in the block editor before it's saved. If that's the case then the proper solution is to handle the situation of a missing ID. You could use `uniqid()` to generate a temporary random ID, for example.

Comment: it is beta.... not even RC. you should probably ask on wordpess slack or open a ticket on trac

Comment: What is calling the `widget()` method in your code/how is this widget registered with WordPress?